# Appending a variable to a url in anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following anchor tag:

```
<a href="https://myUrl" target="_blank"></a>
```

I would like to know if I can append a variable to the url like this:

```
<a href="https://myUrl?variable="+myVariable target="_blank"></a>
```

If not, what is the best way to naviagate to my desired url?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can append a variable, but not like that.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Is your variable Razor?  Or JS?  Why is this tagged asp.net mvc?

Comment: I am doing this in Asp.NET MVC

Comment: And the rest of my questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parenthesis syntax of razor if this is MVC:

```
@{ 
    var strFTP = "Ftp/";
}

<a href='@("http://localhost:8001/" + strFTP)'>Link</a>
```

This will generate an HTML element like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8001/Ftp/">Link</a>
```

What

```
@()
```

of Razor means is that this line of code is Razor syntax and you are concatenating two values, one is string, and one is a variable (**strFTP**) with of course string value on my example.

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript :D

First give your element an ID

```
<script>
document.querySelector(#mine).setAttribute("href", `http://myurl.io `${myVariable}`) 
</script>
```

---